# Retrieving the COM class factory failed due to the following error: 80070005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a big problem on my website.

I'm trying to implement A bank gateway but this error is coming up all the time

[image: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {78EEF9EE-38E9-11D5-9B13-00E0B8184571} failed due to the following error: 80070005.]

so id any body can help please help.

Comment: Did you consult the documentation of the component you are using to try to find out more details about what this error means? Did you contact the author of the component? Stack Overflow is not a technical support forum for some (unknown) components.

Comment: yes, I did.

they asked me to register a dll file on the server and that is what I did exactly.

but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Did you restart the web server after registering the component? Also this looks more like a permission issue rather than a component not being registered issue. Now look at the right section on this page. Do you see the `Related` section, just underneath the ad? There are similar questions already being asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error has been solved by enabling the 32 bit on the IIS, and giving the full Permission  for the dll file.